# How to make Android emulator boot faster

Tags: java, android

I'm currently stuck with using Atom CPU desktop for my Android app development. What are the ways to improve its boot time. When running the emulator I can see that the number of cores used by the emulator is just one, I'm running the emulator from within the Eclipse ADT plugin.

- How can I make the emulator use two cores instead of just one?
- What are the emulator setting that will make boot faster?

My android project will be mainly a PhoneGap + jQuery android app.

Comment: Try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator][1] it works very well for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Comment: check enable quick boot to make emulator fast check https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031415/2826147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make the emulator use two cores instead of just one?

You can't, sorry.

> What are the emulator setting that will make boot faster?

You should try to use one of the x86 emulator images (available now for 4.0.3 and 2.3.3). Beyond that, I am aware of nothing that will speed up the boot time.

Note that you can leave your emulator running for extended periods of time -- you don't need to close and reopen it to run a new copy of your app, for example.

Comment: When you say "x86 emulator images" are you referring to vm image like vmware image? or this is a different thing?

Comment: @xybrek: No, I mean that in the Android SDK Manager, you will see for 4.0.3 and 2.3.3 you will see "Intel x86 Atom System Image" as an option. If you download that, you can create your AVD for your emulator using that image. That will then execute native x86 instructions, instead of converting ARM instructions to x86 on the fly (as the Android emulator does with the ARM system images).

Comment: I have downloaded that Atom System Image, however the emulator display is just black.

Comment: BTW, is there any "snapshot" setting for the x86 system image or it's just for the ARM version image?

Comment: @xybrek: "however the emulator display is just black" -- that's certainly disappointing. If you are running on Windows, I think there's an Intel thing you need to download in the Extras portion of the SDK Manager. Regarding snapshots, I have never used them, but the checkbox is enabled for them for me in the AVD Manager for both x86 and ARM.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install android in virtual machine and connect it to eclipse. It is really faster than default emulator(load within 40 seconds).

First you have to install Android x86 in VMware workstation. Here you can download [android-x86-vm-20120130.iso.gz](http://www.mediafire.com/?l3vauu9v9yjb8ba)

Then you have to connect your VM to eclipse IDE. First run ICS from your VM and open up android command prompt. (Navigate to applications and run **Terminal Emulator**)

Type "**netcfg**" in terminal to find out IP of your vm

Then go to cmd(windows command prompt) and move to "platform-tool" folder in your android installation path(in my case cd C:\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools)

Then type "**adb connect your ip**" command (adb connect 190.156.10.122)

Now you can debug your android application in vm without pain.
Try [this](http://androidjam.blogspot.com/2012/11/faster-adroid-emulator.html)

Comment: @Peter: I can't explain all the steps here in detail. But i edited my answer and included the essential parts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://android-x86.org/ to run a version of android that can utilize your CPU a lot better. I think you need to run it in a virtual machine.

I'm afraid that setting this up is a little more complicated than just running a virtual device straight from the android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to booting faster, the latest Android Emulator v26.2 now has a feature called Quick Boot, which after the initial cold boot of the AVD will boot in under a few seconds for subsequent boots.

[image: Quick Boot feature in Android Emulator v26.2]

Learn more here: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-emulator-2620-canary-with-quick.html