# Is there a better (i.e. faster) Android emulator for debugging?

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Is there a faster Android emulator than the one the comes with the SDK? One that can attach to the Eclipse debugger?

Can BlueStacks or YouWave be used for debugging?

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Comment: I don't think so, but you could take a look at [speeding up that one](https://www.google.ca/search?q=android+speed+up+emulator) instead.

Comment: Personally, the only two good alternatives I've found are 1) a faster CPU and lots of RAM, and 2) using an actual handset :)

Comment: @paulsm4 +1 for real handsets. Even my Nexus One performs miles ahead of the emulator.

Comment: Try to use the Intel image for your AVD and turn Hardware Accelaration on. Or you use Android x86 for debugging.

Comment: Nevertheless it's a duplicated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037908/how-to-make-android-emulator-boot-faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Comment: Not really a duplicate. I'm not looking to speed up the stock emulator (like the other questions). This is the only question that I can find that specifically asks for replacements.

Comment: @Eric - on my laptop, it's more like "parsecs".  Or maybe even "light years" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use the Bluestacks player for debugging. You'll have to connect it like so:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1
```

It's fast but it's only available for the Android version 2.3.7.